# Не удается установить splashscreen в PhoneGap-приложении для Android — что не так?

Tags: android, phonegap, config, экран

В config.xml есть следующие строки:

```
<platform name="android">
        <splash platform="android" density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash platform="android" density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
<platform name="ios">
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
```

Для iOS заставка отображается, для Android нет. 
Все файлы изображений на месте, все пути верные, XML-формат соблюдаю согласно инструкций: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/ и https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ru/latest/config_ref/images.html#%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-splash

Но заставка не отображается - проверял на нескольких устройствах. Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо быть осторожным с тем, что выдает **PhoneGap CLI** при создании приложения, в частности что он пишет в файл **config.xml**. Я доверился конфигу, который был сгенерирован автоматически, в итоге PhoneGap CLI вставил атрибут **density**, а нужно использовать: **qualifier**

к примеру:

```
<splash platform="android" qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
```